# WordPress Page content read more

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

EDIT:

I have a custom php function setup to show the wordpress post excerpt and when the read more link is clicked the excerpt is hidden and the main content displayed. However i want the read more button to become a hide button for when the content is expanded.

```
<?php the_excerpt();

echo '<a value="show more..." onclick="$(this).prev().hide(); $(this).next().show();" >Read More</a>';

echo '<div style="display:none">';
echo the_content();
echo '</div>'; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to keep it simple, you can do something like this:

```
<div id="shortcontent">
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$('#shortcontent').hide();$('#fullcontent').show();">Read more</a>
</div>

<a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>

<div id="fullcontent" style="display: none">
    <?php the_content(); ?>

    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$('#fullcontent').hide();$('#shortcontent').show();">Hide</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much sUP im very new to this and this is just a project to learn different things so your simple solution was great!

Comment: its always good to learn new things.. there's just so much to learn :). next step would be keeping the code a little bit more cleaner by pointing the onclick parameter to a javascript function insted of the explicit javascript code that there is now